# Invoke method in OOP PHP

Tags: php, oop

I am very new at OOP, and i want to get things right at the first learning cycle.

I have a HTML form:

```
<?php
include("classes/Gaestebog.php");
$gaestebog = new Gaestebog();
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Navn:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="navn" value="Patrick" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Besked:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="besked" value="Hej med dig !!" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="opret" value="Opret" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and a Guestbook class:

```
<?php
class Gaestebog {

    public function Gaestebog() {

    }

    public function getPosts() {

    }

    public function addPost() {

    }
}
?>
```

I want the :Guestbook to invoke the addPost method on form submission. How would i approach this?

Comment: By first adding an example in the form of code ;)

Comment: `" i want to get things right at the first learning cycle."` Don't expect to be able to do that. It's a learning process. If you're new to it and start writing code now, you will (hopefully) hate that code  within two weeks. If not, you haven't learned enough.

Comment: Well, call the `addPost` method. Without a more detailed problem description or code there's hardly any more to say.

Comment: Golez, i just don't want to learn odd ways of doing stuff, in that way i want to get the approaches right from the start :-)

I've added my code to the post now.

Comment: any particular reason why you're still using the PHP4-style constructor? Best to start using `__construct()`, because I think the PHP4 constructor might not be around for much longer

Comment: Thank you Elias! That is what i ment by getting things right the first time :-)

I have absolutely no experience on OOP PHP syntaxes, and i've only just started a few months ago with the whole OOP concepts in my Java class.

I'll use __contruct() from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST)) {
    include("classes/Gaestebog.php");
    $gaestebog = new Gaestebog();

    $data = array(
        'title' => $_POST['title'], 
        'author' => $_POST['author'],
        'content' => $_POST['content']
        // etc. 
    ); // Do not forget to validate your data

    $gaestebog->addPost($data);
}
?>
<!-- The HTML part... -->
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what i wanted.

I know this is beyond my original question, but in case i was going to use the MVC architecture, i suppose the Controller would be doing the validation (?)
In that case, how would i catch the data and pass it to the controller?

Comment: The validation is for the Model. It's the better practice. Of course, you can do it in the Controller, too, if you want. How to catch the data? What do you mean?

Comment: If i was to use MVC, and the HTML form is my View, would i still be handling the submission above the HTML in the View page?

Comment: No. Your View, Controller and Model are different files in different folders. If you want to use MVC maybe it will be better to use a framework, e.g. Zend Framework. I'm not sure if I could explain it here because there is not too much space, so you better start reading about MVC structure and the Actions in the Controllers.

Answer (score 1):

```
get an object of your class and then call the function..

for example.. if your submit button name is 'submit' and your class name is Guestbook, then in your action page-
$guest = new Guestbook();

if($_REQUEST['submit'])      // to check that submit button is clicked
{
 $guest->addPost($data); //where data array is what to be saved from post
}

you have to include that class file in your action page like..
require '...';
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd do this exactly as you'd expect:

```
if ($_POST) {
    include 'classes/Gaestebog.php';
    $gaestebog = new Gaestebog;
    $gaestebog->addPost($_POST);  // <-- example guess...
}
```

The basics of instantiating classes and calling their methods is not that hard. There is almost no wrong way to do it. The trick is to use object oriented programming to its full potential and structure your objects in a good way, which is something you'll need to get used to over time. See [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/) to get a taste of what's coming your way.

Answer (score 0):

In order to link the submit of the form with the `addPost()` you should create an action url an write a PHP script. A very first approach would be to write something like:

```
require_once("classes/Gaestebog.php");
$gaestebog = new Gaestebog();
$gaestebog->addPost();
```

the main issue with this is that you leave the responsibility of extracting the form values from the post to the Gaestebog. A better approach would be to parametrize the `addPost()` an let the action handle that:

```
require_once("classes/Gaestebog.php");
$navn = $_GET["navn"];
$besked = $_GET["besked"];
$gaestebog = new Gaestebog();
$gaestebog->addPost($navn, $besked);
```

in this way you decouple the view (i.e. the html page) from your model (i.e. the Gaestebog class). There are more "advanced" ways of handling this with generic action handlers and a little help of .htaccess mod_rewrite (most PHP MVC frameworks use this approach) but if you are learning I would suggest to start this way.

Finally, bear in mind that this is just the first step; one of the next things to consider is data validation and error reporting. You generally do validation on the server side and if you want to improve the user experience you also do it in the client side. The server side part is generally coordinated by the action working with the model. The client side is done in the HTML view.

HTH